# Add Confguration in pom.xml at runtime in dockerfile

Tags: shell, maven, docker, unix, dockerfile

I am trying to build docker image.

Steps in dockerfile

1.pull code from gitlab
2.Maven Build code from gitlab**

However maven build is failing, when i am building docker image and reason is surefile couldn't fork

Below is printed in logs

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
>   (default-test) on project DFDMWeb: Execution default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The
>   forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or
>   System.exit called?

However I know the workaround for above i.e to add below line in pom.xml in configuration for surefire plugin

**false**

pom.xml contents for surefire plugin is like below after that

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.18.1</version>
   <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have tested the above workaround by manually copying source code in aws EC2 instance and modifying the pom.xml file with useSystemClassLoader as false in pom.xml for surefire plugin

After doing so when i ran below command
docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .

Image was created successfully.

**But now the problem is i am cloning repo from gitlab and I don't know how can I add false in surefire plugin configuration in pom.xml at run time using dockerfile ?**

Anyone having any leads would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know I can make changes in the repository and modify pom.xml and commit.
but what if I am not authorized to make commits in repository ?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html

Comment: Do you intend to run tests while building a docker image? You could try to run maven with -DskipTests option to skip maven-surefire-plugin execution.

Comment: @vitalyros Thanks for the suggestion, atleast now I can build docker image and run it. But is there any other alternative without disabling maven unit test ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `useSystemClassLoader` parameter with mvn command option `-Dsurefire.useSystemClassLoader=false` i.e. change your dockerfile to run mvn command like this `mvn install -Dsurefire.useSystemClassLoader=false`

The option is mentioned as a "User Property" in surfire plugin's docs 
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useSystemClassLoader